# Reconfiguring large Hyper-V network for speed with failover

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, hardware, windows-server-2012-r2

I currently have 10 IBM x3650 M4 Servers. Each consisting of a minimum:
- Dual Xeon
- 192GB - 384GB
- 2TB SSD RAID 10 (8 x 500GB Drives)
- 4NIC

All hardware is redundant, PSU, CPU, RAM etc. Each PSU is plugged into seperate PDU's.
NIC's are configured as 2 teams. one for main, one for backup/failover. Each team is on a different physical switch. I have redundant routers.

I also run a backup machine x3630 with a 27TB RAID5 for backup.I use Altaro backup for weekly backups, and also have a php / powershell being triggered daily to backup the sql databases, and then copy to the backup machine.
Some important sites use Replication, only 4 virtual machines at this stage. These repliucate to the backup server.

Each machine is setup for Hyper-V and hosts around 20 Virtual Windows boxes. 
I've done reasonably well to eliminate any single points of failure. If a machine dies. We would turn on replicated machines and restore from backup onto a spare host - which we always have on hand.
I'm curious about pooling resources, or a better way to use hardware. I want to ensure that if a host dies. Services continue to run. I need to sleep easier at night.

I've done a little reading on Volume shared / clustering, SCVMM and event attended a MS course on this (the course speaker spent most of his time working out quirks and bugs) I've read alot of blogs where the management of SCVMM causes enough issues to negate its usefulness.
Machines are currently workgrouped. Used to run AD in 2003/2008 but were forever fixing DNS issues and uysers were constantly unable to log on for x or y reason. Workgroup while providing less security provided more reliability through concrete straight forward settings and troubleshooting.

What are some suggestions on how I can improve my processes and ways of doing things. I love the idea of poolng resources. How is everyone else configuring networks such as these. Do i need some extra hardware - such as 10GBE, or fibre ? I used to have alot of IO issues running traditional hard drives. Converting to SSD's fixed this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So all of your virtual machines are running on local storage on each host and you're "failing over" those virtual machines to other hosts when there's a host failure by using Hyper-V Replica? If so then yes, there's a much better way to do that. Create a Failover Cluster between all of the hosts, implement a Cluster Shared Volume between all of the hosts, move your virtual machine storage to the CSV and configure the virtual machines as highly available roles in the cluster. Then when a host failure occurs those virtual machines on the failed hosts will be instantiated on the remaining hosts.

Comment: partially correct. But in the event of a failure, we only use HV replica for sites that are VIP. Others we just restore from Altaro, followed by SQL restore. We would only use this if a mainboard or raid controller failed in a host.

Another question regarding this is network overhead. Is this going to kill my network ? Any idea on requirements ?

Comment: Another question I have regarding this is implimenting AD etc...

What services are physical and what are virtual ? I'm guessing virtualize the lot...